# Using date() with in_array() or array_key_exists()

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Here is an array I have to work with:

```
array ( [0] => monday [1] => thursday [2] => saturday [3] => sunday )
```

I need to run an if/else statement to check if today's day is in that array.
This does not work

```
// Pretend today is thursdsy
$day = date('l');
$list = array ( [0] => monday [1] => thursday [2] => saturday [3] => sunday );

if ( array_key_exists($day, $list) ) {
    echo "its there";
} else {
    echo "not there";
}
```

Neither does the in_array() version. Not sure if there is a problem using the date() with either of these functions?

If I print_r the $day i get the correct value 'thusday'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list has the data in the values instead of the keys.. that is why array_key_exists is failing. Instead use in_array (also since your array week days represented in all lower case... you should do the same with with the supplied $day to get a match)

```
if (in_array(strtolower($day), $list){
   // whoop there it is..
} else {
   // not here.
}
```

Comment: You could make it more clear by stating you need to use `strtolower()` with `in_array()`.

Comment: @Orangepill No worries. It's just a small touch-up to improve it. :)

Comment: Although with the did a print_r($day) it was showing as lowercase which is why I didn't think to add strtolower(). Very strange

Comment: @user2260007 You should generally force data into what you expect it to be, just in case it isn't, causing the entire script to fall over.